# What is wrong with insert query which contain Now()

Tags: mysql

I am implementing employee attendance system. 
Can you please tell me what is wrong in the following query:

```
INSERT INTO tbtimedetail (outTime) VALUES (NOW()) WHERE empID= '$empid_var' and outTime='NULL';
```

Structure of tbtimedetail is:

```
CREATE TABLE tbTimeDetail(
timeID Int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
empID Int(5),
dateDetail Date NOT NULL,
inTime Time NOT NULL,
outTime Time NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (empID) REFERENCES tbempdetail (empID)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert` only *adds* rows to a database. A *where* filter doesn't make sense in that case.

It looks like you're trying to *update* existing rows:

```
update tbtimedetail
  set outTime = NOW()
  WHERE empID= '$empid_var' and outTime is NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT` like this:

```
UPDATE tbtimedetails t
SET t.outTime = NOW()
WHERE t.empID = '$empid_var' AND t.outTime IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Matt, you should use IS NULL to check if it is null or not?

Also Try CURRENT_TIME() method instead of NOW().
Refer the below url for more Mysql time related methods and operations:
http://www.roseindia.net/sql/sqldate/mysql-time-function.shtml